# Is it possible to add Office 365 as a identity provider in AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using AD B2C custom policies and I have a requirement that along with Facebook/ Google login I need to add Office 365 login too. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

AAD B2C supports federating any OIDC/OAuth2 provider.

See this:
For user flow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant

For custom policy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga